# How to get to Barcelona airport from downtown during the marathon 2021

Tags: airports, taxis, barcelona

So I’m staying at this hotel close to the cathedral and I need to get to the airport in Barcelona tomorrow by 10 AM. According to the marathon website, via Laietania will be closed off, so I’m wondering how to get to the airport by taxi (got a couple of heavy suitcases).

I asked the hotel staff but they were unsure. One of them suggested hauling my stuff to the taxi ranks at Plaça Catalunya but I’m hesitant to drag my luggage through Barri Gotic. While looking at the course map, a better option seems to be to head to Port Vell by Via Laietania, grab a taxi there and take the Ronda Litoral.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My pick would be to walk down towards Passeig de Colom.

Plaça Catalunya looks to be enclaved by the marathon route.

Make sure you leave earlier.